# ASP.Net: Best Way To Handle Multi-Function Form Based on User

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

In my scenario, let's say there is a ASP.Net 4.0 C# page containing a form with several inputs on it.  Based upon which state the user is in, the form needs to act in entirely different ways:  some fields might be required, some not visible at all, some might have different requirements (state A might only allow numbers 1-5, state B numbers 5-10), etc.

So, to simplify things, let's just say for any given input on the form, I need to determine whether or not it's required for the user, again based on their state.  For those of you who run into this scenario quite a bit, what's the best way of implementing a system to handle this?  I can see the following options:

**Hardcoded** - Difficult to maintain, obviously

**Custom Database Rule Framework** - This seems like it would work; however, it would be somewhat of a pain to maintain depending on how complicated the logic is

**Windows Workflow Foundation** - This would be able to handle just about any kind of logic, and be decent to maintain, but I'm not sure how this would do performance wise. (could be stored externally in database)

**Dynamic Code** - Store the logic in a database and run it directly based upon the user.  I've never done this.. is it possible?

That's all I've come up with at this point, but I'm hoping someone out there has found an elegant solution to handle scenarios with complicated forms like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never worked with WWF, but I have encountered a scenario like this and implemented an entry form for it that works well and is easy to maintain once you understand the system.

I will discourage you from using hardcoded logic because any degree of complexity will quickly become impossible to maintain.  I tried a hybrid approach that included some hardcoding initially and it did not turn out well.

I ended up creating, as you call it, a custom database rule framework.  It is a little extra work to set up config forms to associate user groups with certain codes and pieces of functionality, but in the end it is well worth it for everything to automatically configure itself.  Also in my case I was able to farm out user & code setup work to a supervisor in the department that uses the application, so that is a big plus.

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding -- not so hard to maintain, just depending on how fluid the rules are.  I.e., if your "states" are relatively fixed, you're not adding new ones or changing the way those states interact with the page, then hardcoding might be fine.  My only recommendation in this case would be to keep it in a separate class so you can re-use it, modify & re-publish easier, etc.

If you want the flexibility to change the rules a lot, create new states (I'm thinking of these as "roles"), then storing the info in a database would make more sense.

Personally, I use the database approach.  It saves me some re-publsihing of the app, and it has allowed me to build additional interfaces for my end-users to have limited capability to manage their own app in terms of role  assignments ("states" as you put it), etc.  For example, my end-users can grant one of their clients (based on the client's login) access to a certain report.  Or in your situation, they could change the min number for some range-validator your .aspx is using.

Since this approach lets me delegate some admin functions to my end-users, it allows them to do on-the-fly changes (to a limited extent), and also saves me a lot of rush-work / do it yesterday work as far as my own to-do list is concerned.

Comment: I was actually meaning state as in the region the user is in, but roles work too.. I was just trying to think of a concrete way to differentiate the users for the scenario